# Spring Batch : How to add ExponentialBackOffPolicy along with the existing SimpleRetryPolicy?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-retry

I have the following SimpleRetryPolicy defined and it works as it should be.

```
<!-- -->
<batch:step id="baseStep" abstract="true">
   <batch:tasklet>
      <batch:chunk
            reader="cvsFileItemReader"
            processor="itemProcessorAsync"
            writer="itemWriterAsync"
            commit-interval="100"
            retry-policy="retryPolicy">
      </batch:chunk>
   </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="retryPolicy" class="org.springframework.retry.policy.ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy">
    <property name="policyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.lang.NullPointerException">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, I want to introduce the delay between the retries and thought of adding ExponentialBackOffPolicy along with the existing SimpleRetryPolicy

```
<bean id="retryPolicy" class="org.springframework.retry.policy.ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy">
    <property name="policyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.lang.NullPointerException">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
                </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
                <property name="multiplier" value="1.5" />
            </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it throwing an error saying that entry can have only one associated bean. How do I achieve this?

**Updated:**

As suggested,  I have created the Retry Template

```
<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="retryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
            <property name="maxAttempts" value="5" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
            <property name="multiplier" value="6" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

however do I associate the above Retry Template with the exception and set the retry-policy?

[image]

also tried

```
<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="retryPolicy">
<bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy">
    <property name="policyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.lang.NullPointerException">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
    </property>
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
            <property name="multiplier" value="6" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but it is not working

[image]

Comment: @mahmoud-ben-hassine - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that exception correctly because you cannot set 2 beans in the value of map against a key. Having said that retry policy and backoffpolicy are conceptually 2 different things and you cannot set backoffpolicy inside a retry policy. RetryPolicy basically deals with whether to retry and other factors like how many time whereas backoffpolicy deals with whether to retrying immediately or wait for a period of time and the nature of wait. Spring provides a utility class [RetryTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/support/RetryTemplate.html) to handle retry programmatically where you can set both these and provide retries with backoff with certain kind of exceptions. For an example configuration using annotation see below.

```
@Bean
public RetryTemplate createRetryTemplate() {
    Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> exceptions = new HashMap<>();
    exceptions.put(RetryOnThisFatalException.class, true);
    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts, exceptions);
    template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(initialInterval);
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    return template;
}
```

Spring Batch provides declarative retry as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html#declarativeRetry) where you can use the above `RetryTemplate`

Quoting from the docs

> The following example shows a declarative retry that uses the Spring
> AOP namespace to retry a service call to a method called remoteCall

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="transactional"
        expression="execution(* com..*Service.remoteCall(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="transactional"
        advice-ref="retryAdvice" order="-1"/>
</aop:config>

<bean id="retryAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor"/>
```

The `RetryOperationsInterceptor` can uses the RetryTemplate you configured above with appropriate `RetryPolicy` and `BackOffPolicy`

Comment: I have updated the question, please suggest.